# cat vs echo or printf to pass data to the stdin of a program

Tags: shell, printf, echo, cat

Let's suppose we have the following program called `myprog`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){
        char buffer[32];
        gets(buffer);
        system("/bin/sh");
}
```

1. It takes the space for the buffer
2. It waits for data from the standard input and copies it into the buffer until a newline is found
3. It executes the shell as child process, then it will wait for commands from the stdin

So we have 2 instructions who will look for data from the stdin.

Let's suppose we would like to pass this data redirecting the stdout of other programs to the stdin of `myprog`, let's take `echo` and `cat` for example.

```
$ cat > cmds
ls
$ { echo "My string" ; cat cmds ; } | ./myprog
file1 file2 cmds myprog
```

So far so good: `echo` adds automatically a newline character at the end of "My string", this causes `gets` to stop reading and `/bin/sh` to read from the output of `cat`.

But let's try other solutions:

1. `echo "My string" ls | ./myprog`
2. `printf "My string\nls\n" | ./myprog`
3. `{echo "My string" ; echo ls ; } | ./myprog`

None of those solutions seems to work.
Neither using a single file and a single call of `cat` works:

```
$ cat > file
 My string
 ls
$ cat file | ./myprog
```

Why this happens? What happens exactly for each of those cases?

Comment: How do you compile it? In case it's not clear, that script can't be run without compiling it. Does it produce any error messages?

Comment: I'm going to guess the buffering on stdin and timing. Also `gets` is horrible.

Comment: Well, #1 should fail; it only outputs a single line.

Comment: Re: timing, note that `cat` is an external program and there is a slight delay while `cat` is started between when "My string" is output and the contents the file are output. In all your other examples, `bash` internals are used to output both lines. This means `gets` may be reading more than just the first line and buffering it for the next call to `gets`, meaning `/bin/sh` isn't getting the data you expect it to. You might confirm by replacing `/bin/sh` with `cat` to see what is actually in standard input when `system` is called.

Comment: @l0b0 What do you mean? I compile the program with a simple `gcc myprog.c -o myprog`
@EtanReisner I know it'is horrible, it's just an example.  
@chepner You are right the first one is clearly wrong, my mistake.
You are right also about timing, after using `system("cat")` and having a look to the content of buffer I can see that something like `{ echo "My string" ;  sleep 1 ; echo ls ; }` works correctly. Thanks. On the other hand `{echo "My string" ; echo ls ; }` causes `gets` to store only `"My string"` into the buffer. Does `ls` still go to the input of `gets` without being copied?

Comment: The timing issue is due to whatever scheduling choices your OS makes regarding when the various processes receive CPU time. It can vary from run to run and based on current system load.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are a little confused in your approach to the program that will take input from `stdin`. If I understand correctly that your goal was to have `system("/bin/sh");` wait on `"ls"` as input from `stdin`, then if you were successful, you would expect to see the error:

```
/usr/bin/ls: /usr/bin/ls: cannot execute binary file
```

You have seen the comments on `gets` - never use it. If you teacher is suggesting you use it, you can tell him it has been dropped from the C standard library due to its security vulnerabilities. Use `fgets` instead.

That said, if you are looking to take input from `stdin` and you want to use that input in a `system` call, then you need to create a string that contains the command you expect `system` to execute -- including any arguments required. Simply calling `system("/bin/sh");` will not work because `system` executes its command in a *subshell*.

Simply build the string you want `system` to execute. A simple example could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 32

int main (void) {

    char buffer[MAXC] = {0};
    char script[MAXC] = {0};

    /* read line 1 into buffer & print */
    fgets (buffer, MAXC, stdin);
    printf ("\n buffer: %s", buffer);

    /* read line 2 into buffer & print */
    fgets (buffer, MAXC, stdin);
    printf ("\n buffer: %s", buffer);

    /* copy "/bin/sh" to script */
    strncpy (script, "/bin/sh ", strlen ("/bin/sh ") + 1);

    /* concatenate script & buffer ( "/bin/sh + line 2" ) */
    strcat (script, buffer);

    /* execute script */
    system (script);

    return 0;
}
```

It basically takes `line 1` from `stdin` and prints it, then it overwrites it with `line 2` which holds the command (name of the script) for `/bin/sh` to call. You can use a simple test script like:

```
#!/bin/sh

printf "\n %s executed : %s\n\n" "$0" "hello /bin/sh"

exit 0
```

Now you can use `printf` to pass both line-1 and line-2 to your program with something similar to:

```
$ printf "%s\n%s\n" "buffer - line 1" "myscript.sh"
```

Which passes one line at a time to your program. Running the code you would expect to see:

```
$ printf "%s\n%s\n" "buffer - line 1" "myscript.sh" | ./bin/system_buff_stdin

 buffer: buffer - line 1

 buffer: myscript.sh

 myscript.sh executed : hello /bin/sh
```

If you have any further questions, just ask.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
As it is actually an exercise I cannot change the source code...but I'm totally agree with what you said. On the other hand `system` executes its command in a subshell...well, my goal is to pass inputs to that subshell from an external program, it can be done for example using `echo` and then `cat`. My question was: why it doesn’t work with whatever combination of commands that output 2 lines?

Comment: My apologies, I see what you are saying.  You can also use process substitution to effectively do the same thing. (e.g. `./bin/system_gets < <(echo "my cmds"; cat cmds)` ) That is where the file `cmds` holds `ls` as in your example. When you `pipe` the block `{...}` or use process substitution, `< <(stuff)` (which is a bashism), you are redirecting a block (or the output from a subshell) containing your two commands to your program. (`gets` and `system`).